Firebase FCM Topic Restrictions
How many devices can you subscribe to per topic in FCM?
We have about 300,000 users and we send push notificiations all users
We didn't find it when we looked up the FCM document.
And are there any precautions when using FCM for 300,000 devices?

There is no restriction to then number of devices but there are restrictions to how many topics one device can subscribe to, from the documentation:

Topic messaging supports unlimited subscriptions for each topic.
However, FCM enforces limits in these areas: One app instance can be
subscribed to no more than 2000 topics. If you are using batch import
to subscribe app instances, each request is limited to 1000 app
instances. The frequency of new subscriptions is rate-limited per
project. If you send too many subscription requests in a short period
of time, FCM servers will respond with a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
("quota exceeded") response. Retry with exponential backoff.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging
